# How to set up `<Primary><Alt><Shift>semicolon` as a shortcut key in xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xubuntu

I'm trying to duplicate Google Sheets' shortcut to insert current date and time stamp under Xubuntu.

I think I'm almost there as I have a shell script `~/bin/clipdate.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
date +'[%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M]' | xclip -sel clip
```

and I've set `/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>semicolon` as `Property` and `/home/****/bin/clipdate.sh` as `Value`.
And it works, I hit the keys, and the timestamp lands in my clipboard nicely.

But I want the exact same keys :/ trying:

- `/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt><Shift>colon` doesn't work
- `/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>semicolon` doesn't work

and I have another shortcut consisting of `<Primary><Alt><Shift>` and another key (L if that matters) and it does work so it seems it's not a question of using all three.

Is this some sort of a bug, am I doing it wrong or is it just not possible for some reason?